# Internationalization in webnms

Tags: internationalization

I want to have another language beside of english in my webnms client, but the drop down menu in webnms have very languages so its annoying for user to select a language! I want delete other languages from shown drop down menu in client startup so client could easyly select a language. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modified the entries in the file LanguagesAndCountries.txt, which is available in

classes/NmsClientClasses.jar
classes/NmsServerClasses.jar

Once you made the changes, update the latest one, in above mentioned jar again.

Comment: thanks for replay but I know this way and I think there must be another way except modifying a jar file.